# Deleting files from wwwroot folder, what I am doing wrong?

Tags: c#, razor, routes, asp.net-core-mvc, wwwroot

With my controller I am able to upload files to certain path. I am trying to figure out how to delete iterated file in my view.

Controllers method:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Moderatorzy")]
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult DeleteFile(string file)
        {
            if (!System.IO.File.Exists(file))
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            System.IO.File.Delete(file);
            return View("Edit");
        }
```

View file:

```
<form asp-action="Edit" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="hidden" asp-for="ID" />
        (...)
        @if (Enumerable.Count(ViewBag.fileList) != 0)
        {
            <dir>Files to download:</dir>
            {
                foreach (var file in ViewBag.fileList)
                {
                    <a class="down" href="Autobus/DeleteFile?file=@(ViewBag.fileDirectory + file)"><dir>@file<span>;</span></dir></a>

                }
            }
        }
(...)
        <div class="text-center">
            <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Zapisz</button>
            <a href="javascript:history.go(-1)" class="btn btn-primary">Powrót</a>
        </div>
<div class="space"></div>
```

Right now I am having 2 issues:

1) `Autobus` is the controller name. `href="Autobus/DeleteFile?file=@(ViewBag.fileDirectory + file)"` gives me path: `/Autobus/Autobus/DeleteFile(...)` instead of `/Autobus/DeleteFile(...)`. Why?

2) After typig manually just one `Autobus` it does not call `DeleteFile` method. Why?

Complete generated route path is: `http://localhost:50686/Autobus/Autobus/DeleteFile?file=C:\Users\asus\Desktop\Praca%20IT\Programowanie\Projekty\DluzynaSzkola\ASP.NET%20Core%20-%20ostatni\Dluzyna_Szkola_2\BasicConfig\wwwroot/uploaded/bus/1.jpg`

P.S. I am guessing it might be something wrong with routing.

Comment: Your missing the leading `/` - `href="/Autobus/DeleteFile?...` (and a delete action should be a POST not a GET)

Comment: @StephenMuecke good points, thank you, but still I am getting `Status Code: 404; Not Found ` and no breakpoints are hitted in `public ActionResult DeleteFile(string file)` method. (updated question)

Comment: You have an AntiForgeryTokenAttribute. That prevents the method from being called via a get. Put the delete button in its own form with a post and add an AntiForgeryToken.

Comment: @Silvermind I moved `@if(...)` out of the previous form, and placed inside the iteration `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                <form method="post" class="adminBtn">
                    <a class="down" href="/Autobus/DeleteFile?file=@(ViewBag.fileDirectory + file)"><dir>@file<span>;</span></dir></a>
                </form>` And I am having the same error.

Comment: And now make it a 'button' instead of 'a' and put the url inside the forms action attribute.

Comment: @Silvermind now I have `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                <form asp-action="/Autobus/DeleteFile?file=@(ViewBag.fileDirectory + file)" method="post" class="adminBtn">
                    <button><dir>@file</dir></button>
                </form>` and the genenated route is: `http://localhost:50686/Autobus/%2FAutobus%2FDeleteFile%3Ffile%3DC%3A%5CUsers%5Casus%5CDesktop%5CPraca%20IT%5CProgramowanie%5CProjekty%5CDluzynaSzkola%5CASP.NET%20Core%20-%20ostatni%5CDluzyna_Szkola_2%5CBasicConfig%5Cwwwroot%2Fuploaded%2Fbus%2F1.jpg` still with error

Comment: Drop the `?file=@(ViewBag.fileDirectory + file)` part of the URL. That only works with GET requests. POST data is sent using `input` fields located inside the form. You need to add an `input` element within the form which has its `name` attribute set to "file" and its `value` attribute set to `@(ViewBag.fileDirectory + file)`.

Comment: Guys, now I have: `@if (Enumerable.Count(ViewBag.fileList) != 0)
    {
        <dir>Pliki do pobrania:</dir>
        {
            foreach (var someFile in ViewBag.fileList)
            {
                <form asp-action="DeleteFile" method="post">
                @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                <input name="file" type="text" value="@someFile" asp-action="@(ViewBag.fileDirectory + someFile)"/>
                <input type="submit" value="DELETE" class="tiny button">
                </form>
            }
        }
    }` and Im getting `RuntimeBinderException` on `@if`row

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My final working solution:

View file:

```
(...)
@if (Enumerable.Count(ViewBag.fileList) > 0)
    {
        <dir>Wgrane już pliki:</dir>
        {
            foreach (var someFile in ViewBag.fileList)
            {
                <form asp-action="DeleteFile" method="post">
                    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                    <input type="hidden" name="file"value="@someFile" asp-action="@(ViewBag.fileDirectory + someFile)" />
                    <button class="btn btn-danger" type="submit">Usuń</button>
                    @someFile
                </form>
            }
        }
    }
(...)
```

Also in my DeleteFile method I had to add ViewBags:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Moderatorzy")]
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult DeleteFile(string file)
        {
            string fileDirectory = Path.Combine(
                      Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "wwwroot/uploaded/bus/");
            ViewBag.fileList = Directory
                .EnumerateFiles(fileDirectory, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                .Select(Path.GetFileName);
            ViewBag.fileDirectory = fileDirectory;
            string webRootPath = _hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath;
            var fileName = "";
            fileName = file;
            var fullPath = webRootPath + "/uploaded/bus/" + file;

            if (System.IO.File.Exists(fullPath))
            {
                System.IO.File.Delete(fullPath);
                ViewBag.deleteSuccess = "true";
            }
            return View("Edit");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

This part of your complete generated path:

`C:\Users\asus\Desktop\Praca%20IT\Programowanie\Projekty\DluzynaSzkola\ASP.NET%20Core%20-%20ostatni\Dluzyna_Szkola_2\BasicConfig\wwwroot/uploaded/bus/1.jpg`

is because of `ViewBag.fileDirectory` in this line of code ->

```
<a class="down" href="Autobus/DeleteFile?file=@(ViewBag.fileDirectory + file)"><dir>@file<span>;</span></dir></a>
```

You use your real path of the file in your server (local computer) for your view and this can make a lot of problems. You should define something like id for each file and then send id of that file to your controller action method and after that then realize this id is for which file and finally delete that file.

So you must change your code like this:

> In this situation the name of your file is id. Although this is not the
>   standard way. We do this just for learning purpose.

Change this line of your code ->

```
<a class="down" href="Autobus/DeleteFile?file=@(ViewBag.fileDirectory + file)"><dir>@file<span>;</span></dir></a>
```

With this line ->

```
@Html.ActionLink( $"Delete {file}", "DeleteFile", "Autobus", new { file = file}, new { })
```

**Now when you click on each of generated links in your browser, your action method `DeleteFile` will receive the file name. and then if you know which directory are your files, you can delete it in your `DeleteFile` action method with one line of code like this**

```
System.IO.File.Delete(fileDirectory+file);
```

> **Notice:**  If your `fileDirectory` path is something like this
>   `C:\Users\asus\Desktop\Praca%20IT\Programowanie\Projekty\DluzynaSzkola\ASP.NET%20Core%20-%20ostatni\Dluzyna_Szkola_2\BasicConfig\wwwroot/uploaded/bus/1.jpg`
>   your action mehtod (`DeleteFile`) will throw an exception. So you must
>   change your code in this way:

```
string fullPath = Request.MapPath("~/uploaded/" + file);
if (System.IO.File.Exists(fullPath))
{
   System.IO.File.Delete(fullPath);
}
```

In this code `~` specify root of your asp.net MVC application and `uploaded` folder is a folder that you use for locating your files (you can change it to your files folder).

**If you change your code in this way you may have some little problems at first but the concept is right and with a little change you can do what you want.**

***I Hope This Answer Can Help You....***